# JavaFX jar running in windows not in Raspberry Raspbian

Tags: java, javafx, jar, compilation

Im developing a small JavaFX application with Intellij.

I've compiled it to a jar with the Intellij artifacts and it works well in windows both from command line `java -jar file.jar` or double clicking the jar.

The app need to be all day running and I chose to use a Raspberry because I think its the cheapest way.

I installed it on the Raspbian the JDK 8 from Oracle the last ARM version in the oracle website `Linux ARM 32 Hard Float ABI    77.78 MB    jdk-8u111-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz`

The JVM is working and shows the correct version with `java -version`. I assume the installation is OK but when I try to run the jar it says:

> Error: Could not find or load main class es.company.MainApp

The `Manifest.MF` is correct and the Intellij JDK version is 1.8.0_66

Comment: I believe JavaFX is no longer part of the JDK for ARM. You will need to get JavaFX independently. From what I understand [this](http://gluonhq.com/labs/javafxports/get/) should work for you (though I know little about Raspberry Pi). Also see [here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main).

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is right, Starting with 8u33, JavaFX has been removed from 
both Oracle JDK for ARM and Oracle Java SE Embedded. Please find the discussion https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=97367&p=678791#p678791
This is how you can download and install javafx on Raspberry - https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/OpenJFX+on+the+Raspberry+Pi